# Angular Material Icon clearly won't align no matter what you do to it? Although Flex Layout directives and CSS affect it, it's just never aligned

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout, google-material-icons

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M5rR.png

I have tried fxFlexAlign - fxLayoutAlign on the parent, giving it an ID and using display:flex + justify-content:center with !important on everything.

The thing is -- all of the above do something to it, it reacts to the CSS and FlexLayout directives but the thing still looks obviously misaligned no matter what.

Upon inspection it becomes clear that it grows from the right bottom corner of its 'container' and simply does not care about aligning in any way.

Is there something I'm missing on dealing with these? I've looked through the documentation + stackoverflow + googled it and can't find a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention in a comment in the answer you posted that you are changing font size and that triggers the problems. I *think* I recall noticing a bug with this - at least I know I've run into it. In addition to font-size you need to adjust width and height accordingly. Practically speaking, it's probably best to define classes to handle all that and apply them to the mat-icon elements. For example:

```
.mat-icon-16 {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

<mat-icon class="mat-icon-16">help<mat-icon>
```

Note that line-height also plays a roll but by default it is '1' so you shouldn't need to change that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and this is the solution to my question but I'd still like to argue that it really sucks having to go through so much hassle just to change the size of an icon.

Comment: I agree completely!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing everything to font-awesome with svg icons, a bit more tedious importing each icon but keeps the bundle small and can't really argue with the value of svg. I'm not touching material icons in the next decade.

Comment: Did you try setting the `font-size` property?

Comment: @Edric Thanks, that is what actually messes things up. If I just leave the font-size whatever it defaults to due to text around it or black magic, things center fine.

Changing the font size, misaligns everyhthing. If I change it high enough, starting at about around 50 size, it will overlay on the text.

I've also tried adding it to a div, span in every combination I could think of.

Working with font awesome svg icons on the exact same thing/space has been just straightforward and perfect.